# Python 3.x - If quitting program, at the y/n conditional how do I make the no answer go back to the start of program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create a high scores program. It has to be able to do the following:
1. Display the names / scores 
2. Add a name / score
3. Delete a name / score
4. Sort list ascending
5. Sort list descending
6. Quit option < this is where I'm having an issue

I can't figure out how to make the y/n quit conditional at the end go back to the start of the program.

```
import sys

#declaring variables
choice = int()
name = str()
score = int()
entry = (name, score)
scores = [("Moe", 1000), ("Larry", 1500), ("Curly", 3000), ("Mirza", 9000), ("George", 100)]

#asking user to choose
print ("Please enter your choice.")
print ("0 = quit, 1 = List players and scores, 2 = Add more scores, 3 = Delete score, 4 = sort ascending, 5 = sort descending")

choice = input()
if choice == "1":#this lists the already pre-defined list
    for entry in scores:
        name, score = entry
        print (name, "\t", score)

elif choice == "2":#this adds a name / score to the list
    print("What is the player's name?")
    name = input()
    print("What score did the player get?")
    score = int(input())
    entry = (name, score)
    scores.append(entry)
    print(scores)

elif choice == "3":#this deletes a name / score from the list
    print("What is the player's name you wish to delete?")
    name = input()
    print("What is said players score?")
    score = int(input())
    entry = (name, score)
    scores.remove(entry)
    print(scores)

elif choice == "4":#this sorts in ascending order
    scores.sort()
    print(scores)

elif choice == "5":#this sorts in descending order
    scores.sort(reverse = True)
    print(scores)

else:#here is a conditional y/n statement to quit program
    print("Are you sure you want to quit? Please enter y for yes and n for no")
    response = input().lower()
    if response == "y":
        sys.exit(0)
##    elif response == "n":
    ###How do I make the N conditional go back to the start of the program???? I can't figure this out.
```

Comment: Put the whole thing in a `while` loop: `while response != "n"` ... initialize `response` to `"n"` before the loop...

Comment: read up on loops in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will definitely need a loop of some kind.  This could work for you:

```
while True:
    # do some stuff

    if (want_to_go_to_start_early):
        continue # Go back to the start of the loop

    if (want_to_exit_loop):
        break    # Exit the loop

    # do other stuff in the loop

    # at the end of the loop it goes back to the top

# stuff outside the loop (only gets reached after the 'break')
```

Comment: I appreciate everyone's answers, this was the easiest way to implement the loop into my program at least to me as a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
exit = ''
while( exit != 'yes' ):
    menu() # print menu
```

in menu you if exit will get set to 'yes' program ( loop ) will end.
So you can have choice like - Exit program? where you set exit to 'yes', and you can aswell ask for confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different take on the problem would be to recursivly call your main sequence again on the "no" condition and return on the "yes" condition.

```
def main():
    #do stuff

    if(condition == 'y'):
        return;
    else:
        main();
```

Answer (score 0):

your going to need to enclose your main program in a loop like:

```
def display_menu():
    start_over=False
    print ("Please enter your choice.")
    print ("0 = quit, 1 = List players and scores, 2 = Add more scores, 3 = Delete score, 4 = sort ascending, 5 = sort descending")

    choice = input()
    if choice == "1":#this lists the already pre-defined list
       ...

    ....
    ....
    if choice == "0":
       start_over=True

    return start_over

while true:
    play_game()
    ...
    ...
    start_over_flag=display_menu()
    if not start_over_flag:
         break

sys.exit()
```

Read up on looping mechanisms and functions in [the python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/index.html). The Docs will become your best friend these next few months.

make sure you are reading the right version (I linked you the latest, but you may be using 2.7 instead of 3.x)